# Grails - Invoking Shiro login action in service

Tags: xml, grails, service, action, shiro

I have rather unusual problem - I need to make mobile device login to the database system on Grails. The mobile device is sending XML files and they are used as data transfer between device and database application. First thing I must do is authotication on database based on sended XML file. As I coosed the Shiro as security framework, now I must make signing in from XML reading service. Couls some one help me on this?

Here is my try on making it work. 
    import shiro.ShiroRole
import shiro.ShiroUser

```
class LoginService {

 def shiroSecurityService

 def AuthController

 def params

 def confirmation() {

    def path = System.properties['base.dir']    

 def file = new File (path+"/web-app/xml/ConfirmationRequest.xml") 

 def records = new XmlSlurper().parse(file)

   if(records.user.username=='klemens'&&records.user.password=='kot12345')
    {
        params.username='klemens'
        params.password='kot12345'
        AuthController.signIn(params)
    }

  }
}
```

Ofcourse, it doesn't make, it hangs on this error:

```
ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: Cannot get property 'params' on null object
Message: Cannot get property 'params' on null object
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i think that you should rely on Shiro SecurityUtils Class and dismiss the use of AuthController on your service, something like this:

```
 def confirmation() {


    def path = System.properties['base.dir']    

    def file = new File (path+"/web-app/xml/ConfirmationRequest.xml") 

    def records = new XmlSlurper().parse(file)
    Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject()
    UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(records.user.username, records.user.password);
    currentUser.login(token);
    currentUser.isAuthenticated()
  }

  }
```

and don't forget to read the [manual](http://shiro.apache.org/subject.html)

Comment: Nick, remade code with your hints and new imports - now it looks like this:    `import shiro.ShiroRole import shiro.ShiroUser
import javax.security.auth.Subject import org.apache.shiro.authc.UsernamePasswordToken import org.apache.shiro.SecurityUtils -   rest like in yours example` - If I run I got this error: `ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: No SecurityManager accessible to the calling code, either bound to the org.apache.shiro.util.ThreadContext or as a vm static singleton.  This is an invalid application configuration.` So there problem with SecurityManager.

Comment: Hi, i think that in this thread Les resolved this issue. http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Issues-with-Shiro-plugin-upgrade-from-1-0-to-1-1-SNAPSHOT-td2267377.html

Comment: Can't seen the topic to this, because Nabble don't work now, but searched web: `def login = records.user.username.text() def pass = records.user.password.text()    
    Subject currentUser = getSubjectByLogin(login) //UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(login, pass); //currentUser.login(token); //currentUser.isAuthenticated()
}
      public Subject getSubjectByLogin(final String login) { 
      PrincipalCollection principals = new SimplePrincipalCollection(login, shiroDbRealm) 
      return new Subject.Builder(SecurityUtils.getSecurityManager()).buildSubject() 
      }`

Comment: And now I got this error: `ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader - Error executing bootstraps: realmName argument cannot be null. Message: realmName argument cannot be null.` The wierd is that shiroDbRealm **is mine app Realm name** - i even define it in LoginService with `def shiroDbRealm` - Hmm...